# Text rotator with pause in the end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a text rotator with a pause on 3 seconds in the end and then repeat. I have found a relevant script but have some problems with adding the pause in the end.

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/AmruthPillai/pen/axvqB/

Script:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        rotaterator: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                fadeSpeed: 500,
                pauseSpeed: 100,
                child: null
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function() {
                var o = options;
                var obj = $(this);
                var items = $(obj.children(), obj);
                items.each(function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                })
                if (!o.child) {
                    var next = $(obj).children(':first');
                } else {
                    var next = o.child;
                }
                $(next).fadeIn(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
                    $(next).delay(o.pauseSpeed).fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
                        var next = $(this).next();
                        if (next.length == 0) {
                            next = $(obj).children(':first');
                        }
                        $(obj).rotaterator({
                            child: next,
                            fadeSpeed: o.fadeSpeed,
                            pauseSpeed: o.pauseSpeed
                        });
                    })
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rotate').rotaterator({
        fadeSpeed: 0,
        pauseSpeed: 100
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for 3 seconds or whatever interval you like using setTimeout call. I've updated your code. Check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMJQYy

```
if (next.length == 0){
                                    next = $(obj).children(':first');
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $(obj).rotaterator({child : next, fadeSpeed : o.fadeSpeed, pauseSpeed : o.pauseSpeed});
                }, 2000);
                            } else {
                $(obj).rotaterator({child : next, fadeSpeed : o.fadeSpeed, pauseSpeed : o.pauseSpeed});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the function already uses `pauseSpeed` to delay the `fadeOut` so I added the following:

```
var nextDelay = $(next).is(':last-child') ? o.pauseSpeed + 3000 : o.pauseSpeed
```

I check if the next element `.is(':last-child')` and add `3000` to the value `o.pauseSpeed`
and used `nextDelay` instead of `o.pauseSpeed` to delay the `fadeOut`

[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/Maher-Fa/pen/oZgOJN)

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    rotaterator: function(options) {

      var defaults = {
        fadeSpeed: 500,
        pauseSpeed: 100,
        child: null
      };

      var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        var o = options;
        var obj = $(this);
        var items = $(obj.children(), obj);
        items.each(function() {
          $(this).hide();
        })
        if (!o.child) {
          var next = $(obj).children(':first');
        } else {
          var next = o.child;
        }

        $(next).fadeIn(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
          var nextDelay = $(next).is(':last-child') ? o.pauseSpeed + 3000 : o.pauseSpeed
          $(next).delay(nextDelay).fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (next.length == 0) {
              next = $(obj).children(':first');
            }
              $(obj).rotaterator({child: next,fadeSpeed: o.fadeSpeed,pauseSpeed: o.pauseSpeed});
          })
        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rotate').rotaterator({
    fadeSpeed: 500,
    pauseSpeed: 100
  });
});
```

---

related code is this:

```
$(next).delay(o.pauseSpeed).fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
```

I changed it to this:

```
  var nextDelay = $(next).is(':last-child') ? o.pauseSpeed + 3000 : o.pauseSpeed
  $(next).delay(nextDelay).fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
```

- `$(next)`: is the next element selector.
- `.is(':last-child')`: checks if `$(next)` element [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/#is-selector) the [last-child](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) of their parent
- `.delay(number of milliseconds)`: [.delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue (fadeOut in this case).
- `.fadeOut()`: [Hide the matched elements by fading them to transparent.](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)
- `var nextDelay`: is defined using [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)